# How to fill an ellipse with a Turbulence pattern in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, filter

How do I add the Turbulence filter to an ellipse in inkscape?
I create an ellipse shape.

[image]

I select the ellipse and go to the Filter Editor.  I create a new filter and add the turbulence filter and enable the filter.  Instead of giving me an ellipse with turbulence I just see a rectangle with turbulence.

[image]

By contrast if I use a Gaussian Blur it appears to give my ellipse a blur as desired.

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fill an ellipse with the turbulence pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways are the following (there may be others):

## 1. By using clipping

- draw your ellipse
- duplicate it (Ctrl+D)
- move your duplicate to another layer (optional, for convenience only), which you hide for the moment
- apply turbulence filter to original ellipse
- unhide the duplicate ellipse, select the original ellipse (now with turbulence filter applied and looking like a rectangle) and the duplicate ellipse together, and do Object > Clip > Set.

([General information on clipping in Inkscape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip-Clipping.html).)

## 2. By adding a "composite" effect to the filter

- in Filter editor, first add turbulence effect (as mentioned in the question)
- then add a "composite" effect. The composite effect has two entries: one should be the output of the turbulence effect, the other should be the source graphic. In "Effect parameters", set "operator" to "In" (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of filter editor with turbulence and composite effect]